# Software to migrate database changes using SQL "patch" files?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have 2 MSSQL databases in 2 servers and I need to replicate amendments in schema and in particular tables. Most preferably I need SQL commands to do so. The system should be able to take a snapsnot of initial state of the database and later generate an SQL that would display the changes.

I need to record only particular tables changes in data and I also need to detect changes in table format (alterations of schema). It is desirable that manual adjustment of replication SQL would be possible (so only necessary changes are reflected, in case automated rules allow some unnecessary queries to end up in the patch.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [RedGate SQL Developer bundle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/). Unfortunately I'm not aware of any good open source tool for MS SQL Server.

I think that especially [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) could be helpfull for you. If you are using Visual Studio Team Edition, you can have a look at the VS Database projects. I've heard that some teams are successfully using it for their database change management, but I never tried it myself.